# How to prove convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I want to check convergence or divergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^k}$

I already proved that it converges for $k\geq 2$ and diverges for $0\leq k \leq 1$, but i don't know how to prove convergence for $1 < k < 2$, any ideas?

Edit: no integrals allowed

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that no integrals allowed, the question is from a differential calculus class

Comment: We could calculate the convergence-radius with the cauchy-hadamard-theorem.

Comment: I guess the properties of the riemann-zeta-function are not allowed to use either.

Comment: LOL, this question is from a differential calculus class, but...no integrals allowed? Can anyone explain what a differential calculus entails?

Comment: @Peter Aw, you take the fun out of everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying Cauchy's condensation test, you have that, for $\alpha>0$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^{-\alpha}$ is convergent if and only if $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k 2^{-k\alpha}$ is convergent.

But $$\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{(1-\alpha)k}=\frac{1-2^{(n+1)(1-\alpha)}}{1-2^{1-\alpha}}$$ which coverges as $n\to\infty$ if and only if $1-\alpha<0$.

Answer (score 4):

[Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says that, for $k\gt1$,
$$
\begin{align}
(n+1)^k\left(\frac1{n^{k-1}}-\frac1{(n+1)^{k-1}}\right)
&=n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^k-(n+1)\\
&\ge n\left(1+\frac kn\right)-(n+1)\\[6pt]
&=k-1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac1{(n+1)^k}\le\frac1{k-1}\left(\frac1{n^{k-1}}-\frac1{(n+1)^{k-1}}\right)
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^k}
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+1)^k}\\
&\le1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{k-1}\left(\frac1{n^{k-1}}-\frac1{(n+1)^{k-1}}\right)\\
&=\frac k{k-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hmm, interesting application of Bernoullis inequality. A wonderful read. What prompted you to use that setup? Also, is there an easy proof that the inequality on the second line (bringing $k$ inside the fraction) is sharp?

Comment: That inequality is not necessarily sharp. However, the motivation for this plan of execution was primarily to use telescoping series.  We could also use the mean value theorem to prove $$\frac1{(n+1)^k} \le\frac1{k-1}\left(\frac1{n^{k-1}}-\frac1{(n+1)^{k-1}}\right)$$